# getting an error while set foreign key on my table tbl_AddImages

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_AddItems](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductId]  AS ('SHPLT'+right('0000'+CONVERT([varchar](10),[ID],(0)),(4)))PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ProductId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ProductId),
    [ProductCategory] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ProductName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [ProductCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Descriptions] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Stock] [int] NULL,
    [Discount] [int] NULL
)
```

Here I've created table with primary key constraint and I want to create another table references this primary key. I'm getting this error:

> `CREATE TABLE` failed because the following `SET` options have incorrect settings: `ANSI_PADDING`.

Verify that `SET` options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

Any one help me regarding this? Thank you

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_AddImages]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] AS ('SHPLT'+right('0000'+CONVERT([varchar](10),[ID],(0)),(4)))PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductId] FOREIGN KEY([ProductId]) REFERENCES [tbl_AddItems] ([ProductId]),
    [ImgId] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ImgPath] [varchar](100) NULL
)
```